# Change date format in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, datetime, sql-server-2012

In the files I'm importing to my SQL Server database, the dates are formatted differently in different columns. I've been having issues with (for example) 02-06 getting entered as February 6 or June 2. I will use

```
SELECT [entry_date] = DATE_FORMAT([Date], GET_FORMAT(DATE,'EUR')) 
FROM table_name
```

to standardize the dates within the database, but I first need a way to tell the server what is each source column's date format, so SQL Server will know how to rearrange the date:

- 02-06-2015 = dd-mm-yyyy
- 06-02-2015 = mm-dd-yyyy
- 2015-Jun-02 = yyyy-month-dd

Comment: What format are you expecting your final dates in? Can you please include that as well?

Comment: It can be any, as long as it's consistent. dd-mm-yyyy most likely.

Comment: You could consider the Parse function and apply that to the entry date in your query: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213316.aspx

Comment: Do you have any way of knowing which format is going to be used for each column, or is that completely dynamic?

Comment: @russ - I'll take a look at parsing.

Comment: @ZoharPeled - It's the same for each particular column in each file, and is expected to be the same for files I get in the future.

Comment: then use a different convert style for each column, according to it's format. use the styles in the answer that Nepali Rookie wrote.

Comment: @ZoharPeled - Already tried it, it works for the query in question but has some unintended side effects elsewhere. I left a comment under that answer.

Comment: in the staging table all columns are varchar or nvarchar, right?

Comment: @ZoharPeled - It is, which is why I'm confused that it's giving me a date conversion error when moving it to the staging table. The nvarchar-to-date conversion doesn't happen until later.

Comment: without using his code, can you upload the files data into the staging table?

Comment: @ZoharPeled - Yes, but then I return to the original problem of some dates not being interpreted correctly.

Comment: ok, once you have the columns as string values with known formats, all you have to do is use the `convert` function with the appropriate style for each column.

Comment: That's what I did. I never had SSIS errors until I added the CONVERT function, so I suspect it has something to do with that. I checked my data and all the dates have the same format within a column. That rules out outlier rows with incorrect formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could probably do something like this if each columns are formatted differently:

```
select convert(varchar,cast('06-02-2015' as date) ,105) col1
      ,convert(varchar,cast('02-06-2015' as date) ,110) col2
      ,convert(varchar,cast('2015-Jun-02' as date),105) col3
```

Resultset:

```
|col1       ||       col2        ||     col3     |
|02-06-2015 ||       02-06-2015  ||     02-06-2015|
```

Comment: This works within the server, but utterly breaks the the SSIS package used to import the data. SSIS moves the source data to a staging table, then I use the script with the date conversions in a trigger to format and move the data into a main table. It tells me "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string."

Comment: Sorry I just saw this, which part of the SSIS portion are you using this conversion at? Is it when you are loading the staging table or post-staging during the final load? Not that it may make a difference, but the only other reason I would think you would get this error is if your data is in not correctly "formatted" to be convert to an actual date.

Comment: All the Excel data has the correct format. I checked carefully. The conversion happens between the staging table and the main table. Everything is nvarchar until the final move into the main table, which has a date format for that column. I get date errors still when the data is in nvarchar format, which is strange.